# Use Selenium to click javascript image in Python

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to use Selenium to click on a javascript image on a webpage, but can't figure out how to do it.

The code I have so far is:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://explorer.natureserve.org/servlet/NatureServe?init=Ecol")
assert "NatureServe" in driver.title
#elem = driver.find_element_by_name("")
SciName = driver.find_element_by_name('nameSpec')
SciName.send_keys(names)
mouse = webdriver.ActionChains(driver)
element = driver.find_element_by_name('nameCriteriaForm')
mouse.move_to_element(span_element).click().perform()
```

The last two lines are clearly wrong. What I want to select is located in the page source as:

```
<a href="javascript:save_information('review.wmt')"><img src=" http://explorer.natureserve.org/images/search_now.gif" width="77" height="17" border="0" align="absmiddle"></a>
```

It is located multiple times on the page and links to a gif.

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://explorer.natureserve.org/servlet/NatureServe?init=Ecol")
SciName = driver.find_element_by_name('nameSpec')
SciName.send_keys(names)
SciName.submit()
```